# Replace pattern containing asterisk with other pattern using variables

Tags: shell, sed

I have a file say `12` whose content is

```
$ cat 12

rajesh jain
amit jain
xi11 vddp vss log0 log1 md72a7l_logrepw mfactor='1*mfactor'
1234
5678
```

I have variables `a` & `b` like :

```
$ echo $a
xi11 vddp vss log0 log1 md72a7l_logrepw mfactor='1*mfactor'

$ echo $b
xi11 vddp vss log0 log1 md72a7l_logrepw mfactor='2*mfactor'
```

I want to replace variable `a` with `b` in file `12`

When I give the command:

```
cat 12 |sed -e "s/$a/$b/g"
```

it is not working to replace the pattern

I am working on a program where file & variable value keep changing so I cannot
keep literal strings in pattern to search.

kindly help.

Thanks
Rajesh

Answer (score 2):

This will work for any contents of `a` and `b` as it simply works on strings, not REs:

```
awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" 's=index($0,a){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) b substr($0,s+length(a))}1' file
```

Having said that, if `$a`, for example, can contain backslashes that you do NOT want expanded (e.g. if you want `\t` to be treated as literally a backslash then the letter `t` rather than a tab character), then you need to do it this way:

```
awk -v b="$b" 'BEGIN{a=ARGV[--ARGC]; delete ARGV[ARGC]}
    s=index($0,a){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) b substr($0,s+length(a))}1' file "$a"
```

See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for more details on passing the value of shell variables to awk scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can preprocess your pattern to escape all special characters:

```
a_esc=$(echo "$a" | sed 's/[][*}{]/\\&/g')
```

and then use it in the substitution:

```
$ sed "s/${a_esc}/${b}/" 12
rajesh jain
amit jain
xi11 vddp vss log0 log1 md72a7l_logrepw mfactor='2*mfactor'
1234
5678
```

Comment: This might work for some specific subset of characters in some specific input set but it's not a good general approach as you can't do this reliably for all RE metacharacters.

Comment: @EdMorton Why not? (Assuming that $a will be used as a sed pattern only)

Comment: One small example, the first that comes to mind - imagine what would happen if `$a` contained `\.`. The sed command would convert it to `\\.` which would be escaping the backslash and so turning the escaped `.` into an RE metacharacter. If you add `backslash` to the set of characters you escape so the sed command would output `\\\.` (i.e. escaped backslash followed by escaped dot), that'd fix that case but then would introduce failures for other cases, e.g. `\t` representing a tab. It's just a mess and much simpler to simply operate on strings, which unfortunately sed can't do, but awk can.

Comment: @EdMorton you convinced me. +1 to your answer then :)

Comment: This added \* as expected to my replacement string which hence placed it in the file I was replacing so for me it seems I just need to do this ${val//\//\\/}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `perl` with `\Q` and `\E` sequences. The `\Q` tells `perl` where to **start** escaping special characters, and the `\E` tells it where to **stop**.

```
$ perl -pe "s/\Q$a\E/$b/" 12
rajesh jain
amit jain
xi11 vddp vss log0 log1 md72a7l_logrepw mfactor='2*mfactor'
1234
5678
```